# npm - who is loading a dependency?

Tags: npm

`npm list` displays all package dependencies starting from the root. Is there a way to do the reverse, i.e. find out which paths are pulling in a specific dependency? For example, `npm paths lodash` would print only the paths from the root that are pulling in lodash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there is [`which-module`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/which-module), though I am not sure how it is working.

I wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/cowCrazy/aa30d537e07bc878056adb4adeaebb5d) piece for myself, welcome to use it. It has lots of place for improvement and maybe I'll turn it into a module, but for now that's what I have.

Comment: Thanks @cowCrazy. I tried your code and it worked for me as expected. Yeah, I would definitely recommend making an npm module out of it. As for `which-module`, it's not a command line utility, so less interesting to me.

Comment: Out of curiosity for which modules have you checked it?

Comment: I just checked for lodash, didn't know who was pulling it in. So `node index lodash`